# How to add icon / logo to your token on test network?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, testnets, rinkeby

how do I add token icons on testnet explorers? specifically Etherscan.

[image: how to improve reputations in test network]

[image: how to add icons(rinkeby)]

((just for testing purposes))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a function of the Ethereum Blockchain.
This is the function of the site etherscan.io. The Icons and information about the token are added by the site moderators manually.
I do not think that they will want to add something to the tokens in the 
test network

For the main network, this is done through the page
https://etherscan.io/contactus?id=4&a=0x

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/contactus?id=4&a=0x
redirect to an error page